# How to parse Twitter date/time value in Google Sheets to a format for date time evaluation

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a formula that will evaluate a column for the first and most recent dates that come from an imported Twitter date/time format.  The data is not structured in a true date/time format and I'm struggling to parse this down to then perform the evaluation.

The imported data is structured as such:

```
Thu Jan 31 22:23:00 +0000 2019
Sun Feb 07 21:34:29 +0000 2021
```

The intended output I'm looking for is a min/max mm/dd/yyyy for this column given another parameter as a variable.  I'm not sure if this can be done with a single formula or if two formulas must be used to first parse the data into a new column, then perform a min/max lookup.  Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `datevalue`

```
=DATEVALUE(JOIN("-", RIGHT(A1,4), {MID(A1,5,3), MID(A1,9,2)}))
```

This is just picking up year from last 4 letters in A1, month and year from substrings.

Replace `A` with your column. It will show up as number if you don't format the new column as date.